# How can I use rosbuild_check_for_display in catkin?

Tags: catkin, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### rosbuild_check_for_display in catkin

Hi,
I am trying to catkinize a robuild package. It has a testing section that needs to differ between beeing called with simulation or on a robot. Therefor the rosbuild_check_for_display function in the CMakeLists is used. It will run the simulation if a display is present.
Is there a possibilty to do this in catkin?
Thanks for your time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172141/how-can-i-use-rosbuild_check_for_display-in-catkin?/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin provides no built-in equivalent. You'll need to code it yourself using CMake commands.

Maybe something like this would work:

```
if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
  if (DEFINED ENV{DISPLAY})
    add_rostest(tests/simulation.test)
  else()
    add_rostest(tests/robot.test)
  endif()
endif()
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2